# Copy formula from a comment

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, math-display

When replying to a question it's often useful to copy the $\LaTeX$ source of formulas in it by pressing the edit button and cp&p from the source text. (And eventually modify them in the answer.)

Sometimes these formulas appear in comments, but editing them, thus also copying the formulas from them is only possible above the reputation of 2000.

My feature request is that (while keeping editing restricted to high reputation members) copying from the source was enabled for everybody.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. You don't need to edit anything to see the source code for a formula; you can just right-click on the formula and choose the "Show source" option. I got this: $\LaTeX$ from your post, for example.

Comment: (+1) Really good!

Comment: More to the point: your method also works in comments, not just in posts.  Comments with $\LaTeX$ aren't easy to find, so here's one people can experiment with :-).

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Re: understand — The reason why I raised this was I was unaware that right clicking could help.

Comment: @Gabor It's documented somewhere, but it's hard to find!